# Is "them" needed in my that-clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

"Meet" can be either transitive or intransitive, so the object "them" is optional. But "fulfill" and "satisfy" are both transitive so the object "them" is needed. Is this correct?

> Consumers have new needs that require new products to **meet**.

> Consumers have new needs that require new products to **meet them**.

> Consumers have new needs that require new products to **satisfy them**.

> Consumers have new needs that require new products to **fulfill them**.

Comment: I would say that _them_ is required in all versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without "them", the sentence is grammatically correct, but has quite a different meaning.

The first sentence means that the consumers' new needs need to meet new products. This is nonsense since a need cannot need to meet a product.

If you remove "them" from the sentences with "satisfy" and "fulfill", the word "products" becomes the direct object, which changes the meaning of the sentence to something like:

> The new needs of consumers need to fulfill new products.

Again, it's a nonsense meaning, so while "them" isn't required grammatically, if you want to keep the intended meaning, "them" is required at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't understand why the sentence is grammatically correct without **them**. Aren't **satisfy** and **fulfill** transitive verbs that need to be followed by an object?

Comment: @Learner110 I've added more to my answer. Lemme know if that helps

Comment: Yes, that's very helpful. Thank you!